# Rename Default Controller in Symfony throw error?

Tags: php, symfony

I follow these steps to rename default Bundle in Symfony 3

Rename the following occurrences to TestBundle:

1. **src/AppBundle** folder
2. **src/AppBundle/AppBundle.php**
3. The namespace directive in `src/AppBundle/AppBundle.php`
4. The classname in `src/AppBundle/AppBundle.php`
5. The occurrence in `app/config/routing.yml` to TestBundle too
6. In AppKernel `new AppBundle\AppBundle()` to new `TestBundle\TestBundle()`

Then i go to directory, open cmd and type `php bin/console server:run` and get this error:

[image]

Comment: have you tried to clear cache?

Comment: Take a look at the psr4 section in composer.json.  Be sure to run composer dumpautoload after changing.

Answer (score 1):

In your composer.json

replace your autoload part with:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
```

Comment: @Morgan also dump composer autoload

Answer (score 1):

7. The ocurrences in `app/config/services.yml` to TestBundle
8. The ocurrence in `src/TestBundle/DefaultController.php` to TestBundle
9. In your composer.json, replace your autoload part with:

> 

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "TestBundle\\": "src/TestBundle"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
```

10. Execute `composer clear-cache`
11. Execute `composer install`